# Which payment gateway should be used in cordova app?

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova-plugins

I have to use a payment gateway for hybrid mobile app (cordova, mobile jquery) and it should be in Indian currency. Can anybody suggest which one is best and easy to implement? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use [PayPal-Cordova-Plugin](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Cordova-Plugin)

But unfortunately Indian currency not supported [check here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/rest/currency-codes/#direct-credit-card-payments)